# I need some advice on push ups due to surgery and injuries

Tags: push-ups

I am a beginner with working out and I know one of the best exercises is push ups but due to steel pins in my toes I am unable to do a "real" push up. Are knee supported push ups just as effective or pretty close?

Answer (score 3):

With knee supported pushups, you lift with a shorter lever. So your arms and chest have less force to deliver. Apart from that, the exercise is identical. Depending on how fit you are, you may want to start with pushups from the knees anyway. Once you outgrow this version, you can try to place your lower legs on a padded bench to leave the weight of your toes and still do a full range pushup.

Comment: +1. I was going to say the exact same thing, place shins on a padded bench and do pushups from there.